# python imaplib UID command error: BAD [b'Could not parse command']

Tags: python, imaplib

I am trying to copy a mail using the copy command.

```
imapper.copy(email.uid, 'TEST')
```

email.uid = the uid in this case 1069

TEST = the map the mail should be in

This is my copy function:

```
def copy(self, uid, to):
    #typ, content = self._mailer.copy(bytes(uid), to)
    print (uid)
    typ, content = self._mailer.uid('copy', bytes(1069), 'TEST')
    if typ == 'OK':
        mail = _parse_email(content, include_raw=include_raw)
        return mail
    else:
        raise Exception("Could not copy email.")
```

Since I'm having this error i decided to NOT use variables and hardcode it until it works and than replace it with the variables.

```
typ, content = self._mailer.uid('copy', bytes(1069), 'TEST')
```

This returns the error:

> UID command error:BAD [b'Could not parse command']

I have added bytes() otherwise i get this error:

> TypeError: can't concat int to bytes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It takes a string.  use str(1069) or '1069', not an integer.  Although, they are numbers, the protocol treats them as strings, not numbers.

`bytes(1069)` in python creates a byte array of 1069 zeros, and so you're sending a bunch of nulls.

Comment: Well this is indeed the answer.

I have also updated my repository with this answer thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay so this is my solution:

I've added the bytes UID to the mail object and changed the copy function to use this bytes uid. This solved all problems

I've also made a fork of the easyimap wrapper with my implentations

So with a new feature to copy mails to another mailbox

https://github.com/UGxMvH/easyimap